# Can you change your appearance in-game?

Tags: stardew-valley

So when setting up your character there's quite a few customization options, including over 100 options for shirts, and  RGB metres for hair, eyes and pants colour. Loads of customization is great (and overwhelming), but also a bit pointless if I can't change my clothes or hair colour in-game. I've strolled around the town and menus, but there doesn't seem to be any way to change my appearance.

So, once I've made my character and I've started a game, is it possible for me to change the appearance of my character, and if so, how?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is indeed a way to change your appearance. Spoiler:

> When you reach a 4 heart relationship with the wizard there will be a shrine in his cellar that will allow you to change your appearance.

Answer (score -9):

As far as I know, it is not yet possible to modify your appearence after you have started the game. 
Try to notify the developer, he still has a few ideas he has yet to implement so maybe he'll do yours too.